# selenium library not recognize by docker while it is added by poetry

Tags: selenium, python-poetry

I added the selenium library by using poetry like this `python3 -m poetry add selenium`, and it is showing that it already exists, but then I import this in a project and it shows there is no module named selenium.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. I thought maybe it's that poetry doesn't allow importing from packages we had installed through it, but simply removing and installing selenium worked for me. So I guess it's a matter of this software being pretty new. Try:

```
poetry remove selenium (you might want to reinstall everything)

poetry add selenium
```

then simply import webdriver with

```
from selenium import webdriver
```